# Symmetric system of $3$ equations: $x+y+z=23$, $xy+yz+xz=144$, $xyz=252$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials

I need help solving the following system for all real ordered triples $(x,y,z)$ without guessing and checking:

$$x+y+z=23$$

$$xy+yz+xz=144$$

$$xyz=252$$

Preferably, the solution should use methods taught in high school.

Thanks.

Comment: Use Vieta's formulas.

Comment: I do recognize that these are related to the roots of some cubic, but I'm not sure how to proceed from there.

Comment: My current idea is to use [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) to find $x^2+y^2+z^2$ as well as $x^3+y^3+z^3$, then substitute $x=23-y-z$ to $x^2+y^2+z^2$ to obtain a quadratic equation in $y,z$, then I have no idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Vieta's formula, $x,y,z$ are the roots of the following cubic equation:
$$x^3-23x^2+144x-252=0$$
Now, [use the cubic formula to solve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula).

You could also try guessing and checking for integer roots of $x$. Using the rational roots theorem, roots must be factors of $252$. Then, once you find a root, use synthetic division to get a quadratic and then use the quadratic formuka.

Comment: I doubt if the cubic formula is taught in high school.

Comment: @KennyLau OK, but it can also be solved using guess-and-check and synthetic division, which is what I learned in pre-calc, so I added that to my answer.

Comment: [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) solves this easily.

Comment: so the solution is $x=6, y=3, z=14$ with possible permution of this value

Comment: (+1) Thanks! I didn't realize that you could turn this into one equation that actually solves for both x, y, and z.

Answer (score 2):

The second equation is,

$$y(x+z)+xz=144$$

From the first equation, $x+z=23-y$
From the third equation, $xz=\frac{252}{y}$

So we have:

$$y(23-y)+\frac{252}{y}=144$$

$$-y^3+23y^2-144y+252=0$$

$$y^3-23y^2+144y-252=0$$

Which can be solved by the cubic formula. And perhaps the rational root theorem and checking roots, or graphing and checking is simple way to go if you are willing to accept checking only a few amount of hypothesized answers.

$y=3$

Synthetic division and factoring gives:

$y=6$

$y=14$

Furthermore, by the symmetry of your equations we have:

$$x^3-23x^2+144x-252=0$$

$$z^3-23z^2+144z-252=0$$

Answer (score 1):

We have three equations

$$x + y + z = 23$$

$$xy + yz + xz = 144$$

$$xyz = 252$$

Multiplying the 2nd equation by $z$, we obtain

$$\underbrace{xyz}_{=252} + yz^2 + xz^2 = 144z$$

which can be rewritten as

$$252 + (x + y) z^2 = 144z$$

From the 1st equation, we have $x+y=23-z$. Hence,

$$252 + (23-z) z^2 = 144 z$$

and, thus,

$$z^3 - 23 z^2 + 144 z - 252 = 0$$

Plot this cubic polynomial. Find one root. Use, say, [Ruffini's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruffini%27s_rule) to find the other two. For each of the three roots, $\bar{z}$, we have a system of two equations in $x$ and $y$, one linear and one bilinear,

$$x + y = 23 - \bar{z}$$

$$x y = \frac{252}{\bar{z}}$$

Multiplying the 1st equation by $y$,

$$\underbrace{x y}_{= \frac{252}{\bar{z}}} + y^2 = (23 - \bar{z}) y$$

This is a quadratic equation in $y$, so we can use the quadratic formula. Once we have solved for $y$, we can find the corresponding $x$.